# Difference accessing localstorage chrome vs firefox

Tags: local-storage

I use several html-pages on my (Windows-)computer with javascript to collect and analyse data from an energy consumption monitor device: the "Homewizard Wi-Fi P1 Meter".
The html-files are local, without internet, e.g. "file:///C:/work1/data1.html"

It took me some hill-climbing to discover a surprising difference between Chrome and Firefox.

Conclusion:
In Firefox the storagekeys are 'owned' by the html-file.
In Chrome the storagekeys are 'owned' by the computer.
(or maybe by the user?)

Chrome:
Data stored from a certain page, can freely be accessed from other html-pages, even simultanious. The listing of actual storage-keys is the same on the different pages.
(this way I also find cookies from recently visited websites, and can eat them !)

Firefox:
Data stored from a certain html-file (e.g. "file:///C:/work1/data-1.html" ) can only be accessed from that filepath. The same foldername and filename must be used, otherwise these keys are not visable. (no cookies to find..)
It is however possible to read/write these keys from an other html-file, by replacing "work1/data1.html" with that file.
I keep "data1.txt" and "data2.txt" in the folder, and copy the chosen one to "data-1.html".
They can run simultanious.

Questions:

1. Why the difference, and is this "well-known"?
2. Is there a way to change this behavior,
   can I make Chrome act like Firefox, and/or Firefox like Chrome?

Comment: strange. The `file://` protocol has long been considered insecure and it is banned from accessing `localStorage`